# Hibernation file structure

Tags: windows-7, file-format

In my program I need to decompress hibernation file hiberfil.sys from windows7 64 bit (to search some memory artifacts). I cannot find any good description of the file format over the Internet.

Is there anyone who already met this issue? Maybe someone already recovered the format? I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find some luck with the [bulk_extractor project](http://afflib.org/software/bulk_extractor). If you get the source code, and check out the src/scan_hiberfile.cpp file, it can show you how to open a windows hibernation file.